# python3 converts color codes to different type without me wanting it to do

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors

I am Krijn I am thirteen years old I like to code with Python3.
this time I was working on a little game inspired by [Elemental 4](https://elemental.davecode.me/)
in this game, you combine elements and make new elements if the combination is not used yet then you can submit your own new element. this game was amazing I thought so I started to build my own local version in python.

on to the question.
I made a function that lets you submit your own colors.
but when I upload a color it converts it to a totally different type of color code. i also made a save function that prints the values off two lists

the code the comments are in dutch sorry:
[here the code](https://repl.it/@krijnlol/DefiniteDangerousCylinders)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to make this into a [mcve]. When you're done, [edit] your question. Thanks! <3

Comment: Krijn, welkom hier! As a newly registered member of Stack Overflow, you may want to read the [tour]. (Don't worry, it is short and simple.) It describes the main points of Stack Overflow; one of this is that a question must contain everything to be able to answer it. If your entire program is large, make a smaller one that still has the same problem. I have voted to close but don't worry: if you update your question I will take that back.

Comment: (By the way, your English is very good!)

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/usr2564301 ! I place the question again at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818849/python-3-print-text-using-24bit-html5-rgb-code